# Compressing/Reducing image file in java

Tags: java, image

[One of the image file used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuqKS.jpg)

```
    String dirName=System.getProperty("user.home") + "/deleteme";
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,"a.jpg"));
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();

    byteArrayOutputStream.close();

    byte[] bytearray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
    ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"));
```

This piece of code reads the image file, converts it into byteArray and then stores it back.
Now for most of the image files I tested, the size reduces drastically to just about 15% of the original size.

1. Can someone explain why doing this reduces the image file size.
2. Is there a drop in quality in this process.

[I have compared the images in http://driiqm.mpi-inf.mpg.de and it shows me that the new image has the same quality.]

Comment: How big was the original file? Image file can contain a lot of metadata that you are not copying and are lost. For example [exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif), thumbnail,...

Comment: @Piro One of the image file Original size: 241 kB, After using the code: file size: 35kB

Comment: I have added the image file used, Please check the link at the start of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Your result does not have same quality as original. JPEG always looses some quality but your result looses a lot of it. Exif metadata have been lost but it is marginal difference.

I tested your example image with your writing method and then tested writing it with top quality (For example code that @MauricePerry wrote). Then I compared them with http://driiqm.mpi-inf.mpg.de and with http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi

So original file:

- has size of 228kB
- has embedded [color profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile).
- [Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)
  YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1)

With your method I got:

- size of 35kB
- no embedded color profile
- [Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
- a lot of differences between original and result:

[image: comparison with first result]

With top quality I got:

- size of 272kB
- no embedded color profile
- [Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
- minumum of differences between original and result (but still there are some):

[image: comparison with second result]

I am not sure how did you assume images have same quality, because webpage you posted shows lot of differences. Even with top quality it shows differences and that makes sense because JPEG is lossy format. [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) represents image data as bitmap and some information is lost when converting to JPEG. That is why we have lossless formats like PNG.

I also did what you said - used result image as source image and then input and output are same. I would compare it to reaching local minimum. JPEG -> bitmap conversion produces bitmap where bitmap -> JPEG produces same JPEG data because you are using same function (same quality, same sampling). But if bitmap -> JPEG conversion used different function (for example using top quality this time) there would be more loss of quality.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"))) {
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    JPEGEncodeParam eparm = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img);
    eparm.setQuality(quality, true);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(eparm);
    encoder.encode(img);
}
```

where quality is a float between 0. and 1.

Comment: OP does not want to change image quality. He is asking while file size changed with quality remaining same

Comment: @Piro this is how he can control quality (and file size)

Comment: Yes, I don't want to change image quality. I just want to know why the code I have given works the way it does (it reduces the file size, and I cant tell if the quality of the image has changed.)

Comment: @PariNgang If you try this code, and set the quality to 1 then you should get the same size/ a bit larger image. This gives you a way to check if the default is less than 1.

Comment: @PariNgang note that it's the quality of the encoding, not the quality of the image itself; that's why, if you read and write the same file several times, the quality of the image will worsen.

Comment: @MauricePerry, I read the modified file and wrote it to a new file (using the code I submitted) and there is no change in the file size. [The change in file size happens only in the first time].

Comment: @PariNgang makes sense since the quality factor is the same for both writes.

Answer (score 0):

The quality is being changed to the default value. You write with this default value twice.

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
```

Now the image has been turned to bytes, and compressed using a lossy compression.

```
ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"));
```

That also uses the default compression.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000)) {
        float quality = 1f;
        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg").next();

        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(1f);
        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(img, new ArrayList<>(), null);
        writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out));
        writer.write(null, image, param);
        byte[] bytearray = out.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(bytearray.length);
        Files.write(Paths.get("snap2.jpg"), bytearray, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

    }
```

In this example the byte array will contain the least lossy compression, which is close to the input size. To write it out, don't use ImageIO to read/write it again. Instead, I just wrote the bytes directly to the file.